# Generate PDF report using python in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, fpdf

What is the best way to generate a PDF report in a AWS Lambda function and email the PDF using SES. I will have my function outputs/prints the details to the PDF file dynamically and then attach the pdf as a report to send in an email. I was thinking of using FPDF but seems like it may not be the best option.

Basically my requirement is to generate a pdf report and email in a Lambda function using python.